# javascript scroll of background

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to have canvas background scrolled based onmousewheel.
Bacground is loaded through css. Chrome browser is used.

```
function nerob() {
var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas=x.getContext('2d');
}
window.addEventListener("load", nerob, false);



#canvas {
background-image:url(robot.png);
}
```

Comment: Kindly try harder before presenting a question you're stuck on.  All you have done so far is reference elements and wire up a listener.

Comment: Thanks, you are right,,i m using reference code as later on will move to implementation,,i m trying to keep it simple as possible. i have tried some resarch but no luck yet.

Comment: Do note that you are setting the CSS background image of the canvas. You will likely need to update `x.style` to manipulate the background image